# Checkbox shows up as disabled

Tags: java, jsp, checkbox, struts

I'm mistified why a checkbox would show up disabled.
What do I need to do to enable it?
Already tried using String object for the requestInvoice property, does not help.

JSP:

```
    <fieldset class="aa-list-primary-indent">
            <label class="custombox-wrapper custombox"  data-behavior="custombox">
            <div class="control checkbox"></div>
                <html-el:checkbox  styleId="requestInvoiceCheckbox" property="form(creditCardForm).personalId.requestInvoice" />
                In need of an invoice (factura)
            </label>
    </fieldset>
```

Form:

```
    private boolean requestInvoice = false;

    public boolean isRequestInvoice() {
        return requestInvoice;
    }
    public void setRequestInvoice(boolean requestInvoice) {
        this.requestInvoice = requestInvoice;
    }
```

HTML generated by the browser (Chrome):

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="form(creditCardForm).personalId.requestInvoice" value="on" id="requestInvoiceCheckbox">
```

[image: Screenshot:]

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL added screenshot.

Comment: There may be a css style that disables ceckboxes?

Comment: unlikely.  What would it look like in the browser?

Comment: you may have global css for input type checkbox.

Comment: @user3200809 how would I check that?

Comment: elements may be disabled by css like http://jsfiddle.net/CaY5g/

Comment: @jprusakova can you use firebug from firefox and click 'inspect element' option for your checkbox and then check related css class or style for checkbox.

Comment: @user3200809 I'm going through styles in DevTools in Chrome, and it is not disabled, and not readonly.   Anything else to look for?

Comment: can you host your app and provide us link possible?

Comment: @user3200809 no, can't. It's on internal QA site, full corporate security/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it's a bad question. 
The CSS setup makes the checkbox look disabled, even though it is not.  Bad CSS design. 
All the JSP/Java/HTML code above is fine.